# MoinMoin macro syntax position switch-er-oo

Tags: sed, macros

I have a new version of a moinmoin wiki macro called Color2 that I have installed and now the color declarations come after the content. For example, before, it looked like this to declare, "I am hungry", with a white text color:

```
<<Color2(white,I am hungry)>>
```

Now, it's been changed. They switched it so the color is declared *after* the content:

```
<<Color2(I am hungry,white)>>
```

The syntax can get a little more complicated than this but, in our case, it is most often used in this manner.

I have about 400 pages of content in my wiki where I'd really like to do a color-declaration switch-er-oo. Preferably, I'd like to find all the instances of `<<Color2(white,*)>>` and replace them with `<<Color2(*,white)>>` and then again with red, yellow, blue, etc.

But this is a bit beyond my *grep*, *sed* and *awk* skills. Are there any masters kind and skilled enough to show me how this can quickly be done?

UPDATE:

I was able to make a sweet script based on Philipp's suggestion:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat $1 | sed 's/Color2(\([^)]*\),\([^)]*\))/Color2(\2,\1)/g'

exit 0
```

This elegantly captures most situations quite reliably (those where the color is delimited from the text by a comma, which isn't all of them, BTW). Thanks again, Philipp. Here's the syntax, if we name the script "script.sh": `script.sh /path/to/text_file.txt > /path/to/new_file.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not super sophisticated, but works (for `white`). If you want to do what you planned, then replace `white` with a different color. Not sure, how different your formatting can be, but it may require adjustment of the command. So let us know if this solution doesn't work for you, so that people can give a better reply.

```
cat /tmp/t
<<Color2(white,I am hungry)>>

sed 's/Color2(white,\([^)]*\))/Color2(\1,white)/' /tmp/t
<<Color2(I am hungry,white)>>
```

Comment: Thank you Philipp! This works quite well with one caveat: we need a `g` at the end of the sed command because this string appears multiple times, of course. That much I know. `sed 's/Color2(white,\([^)]*\))/Color2(\1,white)/g' /tmp/t`. I just want to know how it is that you were able to declare a subset of the find string as the first variable. I assume it has something to do with those parenthesis you escaped?

Comment: I think you need /g only if the pattern is found more than once in a string, as sed processes each string, not the text as a whole. And as for the second question, then the answer is "yes" it's called "matching group", you ask sed to remember the matching part in between of the parenthesis. You can have several of them inside the pattern and then refer to them by \1 \2 ... etc.